# Sorting one table data according to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and I want to select all rows from attribute_option table and sort them according to `option_id` column of `product_attribute` table:

**attribute_option**

```
option_id | attribute_id  | option_name

     4    |       2       |  f1 

     5    |       2       |  f2

     9    |       2       |  f3 

    10    |       2       |  f4 

    17    |       2       |  f5 

    18    |       2       |  f6 

    24    |       2       |  f7
```

**product_attribute**

```
rec_id | product_id  | attibute_id | option_id

   1   |      1      |      2      |  4

   2   |      1      |      2      |  5

   3   |      5      |      2      |  25

   4   |      5      |      2      |  4
```

---

For product id 5 **attribute_option** table should be like this

```
option_id | attribute_id  | option_name

    25    |       2       |  f8

     4    |       2       |  f1 

     5    |       2       |  f2

     9    |       2       |  f3 

    10    |       2       |  f4 

    17    |       2       |  f5 

    18    |       2       |  f6 

    24    |       2       |  f7
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you show the desired output?

Comment: What is the relation between `attribute_option` table and `product_attribute` table?

Comment: @user3336969 As the tables are related, will be equal in order by `option_id` both tables.

Comment: But if option_id is the relation, why do you want to sort on the option_id of the other table? It is the same as the first table, since its the relation...

Comment: @user3336969: Can you please show how the desired result set would look like?

Comment: @user3336969: Please format it and update it in the question itself.

Comment: any one getting the question??

Comment: @user3336969: Solved. Check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT attribute_option.option_id,
       attribute_option.attribute_id,
       attribute_option.option_name
FROM attribute_option,
     product_attribute
WHERE product_attribute.option_id = attribute_option.option_id
ORDER BY product_attribute.option_id
```

I think this is what you are asking for...

Answer (score -1):

Please check this. It works perfectly. Gives exactly the output you require. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e952e/4/0

```
SELECT attribute_option.option_id,
       attribute_option.attribute_id,
       attribute_option.option_name
FROM attribute_option,
     product_attribute
WHERE product_attribute.option_id = attribute_option.option_id
AND product_attribute.product_id = 5

UNION

SELECT attribute_option.option_id,
       attribute_option.attribute_id,
       attribute_option.option_name
FROM attribute_option,
     product_attribute
WHERE product_attribute.product_id != 5
```